# Broken Admin Menu in PyroCMS

Tags: php, mysql, pyrocms

I just upgraded an install of PyroCMS manually.
For some reason my admin section is going nuts.

The menu isn't working, and when I try and look at Add-Ons in Admin it throws an error about the module already being in the db.

Any ideas how to fix this?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea why, but this worked:

1. Copied default_modules to copy_default_modules in phpmyadmin (for backup)
2. Removed all rows from default_modules table
3. Visited /admin/modules/
4. Now there's only 3 options in the left nav in admin.
5. Installed the Galleries Module.
6. Everything is back to normal. All menu options in place. Still have all the old blogs and stuff. Hooray.

Answer (score 0):

I think it´s trying to create something new what already exists. Using auto update would fix the problem..

Comment: I think there should be some auto update feature? Or how did you actually do the update - just copying/replacing the files or some other way?